# Was CGI used to make Will Smith look different in the movie Concussion?

Tags: effects, concussion

I was watching [this trailer](https://youtu.be/bbPS7K9falk) about the movie ["Concussion"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3322364/) and to me Will Smith looks very different from the last movie I saw him in just a couple of years ago. Something about his jawline and the shape of the head otherwise(?)

Here is a screen grab from the YouTube video:

[image: Will Smith]

In any case it does not look like these facial features are caused by makeup. And he looks a bit older than the 47 or so that he is. So I thought maybe they purposely wanted him to look a bit different.

Did they use CGI in this movie to make him look different? Or is it a case of me needing to improve my facial recognition skills?

Comment: He also might be sticking his jaw forward a little bit. (And he's a really good actor with good control of his facial muscles, so that could be part of it.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this interview with Smith](http://hiphollywood.com/2015/12/will-smith-jokes-about-his-nigerian-accent-in-concussion/) they used prosthetics that pulled back his ears and changed his hairline:

> But besides taking dialect training Smith also had to undergo a physical transformation to help him look more like Nigerian doctor Dr. Bennet Omalu. “I had a prosthetic that was glued to pull my ears back and that changes the shape of my face,” he explained. “And I had a small piece that changed the shape of the hairline. It was really subtle, but just little things like that.”

Comment: Great find with this answer!

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).